# What does "top" means as a verb? (from Justice league Dark)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

In the movie Justice League Dark, "Constantine" tells the demon Etrigan:

> - Save the bloody rhymes and top that git.

What does "top" mean in this context?

Actually, I have no idea about any of the words  `rhymes` and `git` too.  Can you please help me?

[image: John Constantine]

Comment: Need more context. "Top" has many possible meanings. Could mean "take the head off."  Could mean "dominate" as in "get on top of." There are others. Also, it could be a wonky translation.

Comment: It is probably "take the head of" in this context.  +1

Comment: Loosely, it means, "Stop the damn talking and kill that annoying person".

Comment: It looks like how American movie people think British people talk.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey hehe, in my prior comment I actually typed "It appears to be British English as poorly imagined by American English speakers" before deciding that might be a bit snarky.  Glad it's not just me.

Comment: Americans think we say 'bloody' all the time. Maybe 50 years ago.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Right. Right. You're bloody well right. You got a bloody right to say." So said Supertramp  about 1980 or so.  "Me I don't care anyway."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I still bloody say bloody all the bloody time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'To top [someone]' is British English slang for 'to kill/murder [someone]'. A others have noted, he use of the words 'bloody' and 'git' make it abundantly clear we're dealing with an attempt at British English dialect.

A 'git' is an unpleasant person. It was quite old-fashioned and mildly offensive - the sort of thing my dad said in the 1970s, along with 'berk', 'nerk' and 'wassuk' - but J K Rowling might have saved it from obscurity by making it a favourite epithet used by Ron Weasley to describe teachers and Death Eaters alike.